# spark job performing poorly while converting text files to parquet format

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, bigdata

I have a spark streaming application which is responsible for converting text files into parquet format on the fly, and then saving the data in an external hive table. Please refer the mentioned piece of code which is one of the classes for processing text files into parquet:

```
object HistTableLogic {val logger = Logger.getLogger("file")
        def schemadef(batchId: String) {
    println("process started!")
    logger.debug("process started")
    val sourcePath = "some path"
    val destPath = "somepath"
    println(s"source path :${sourcePath}")
    println(s"dest path :${destPath}")
    logger.debug(s"source path :${sourcePath}")
    logger.debug(s"dest path :${destPath}")

    //  val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true"))
    val conf = new Configuration()
    println("Spark Context created!!")
    logger.debug("Spark Context created!!")

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    println("Spark session created!")
    logger.debug("Spark session created!")

    val schema = StructType.apply(spark.read.table("hivetable").schema.fields.dropRight(2))
    try {
        val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
                                spark.sql("ALTER table hivetable drop if exists partition (batch_run_dt='"+batchId.substring(1,9)+"', batchid='"+batchId+"')")

                fs.listStatus(new Path(sourcePath)).foreach(x => { 
                    val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("inferSchema","true").option("delimiter","\u0001").
                    schema(schema).csv(s"${sourcePath}/"+batchId).na.fill("").repartition(50).write.mode("overwrite").option("compression", "gzip")
                    .parquet(s"${destPath}/batch_run_dt="+batchId.substring(1,9)+"/batchid="+batchId)

                    spark.sql("ALTER table hivetable add partition (batch_run_dt='"+batchId.substring(1,9)+"', batchid='"+batchId+"')")
                    logger.debug("Partition added")
                })

    } catch {
    case e: Exception => {
        println("---------Exception caught---------!")
        logger.debug("---------Exception caught---------!")
        e.printStackTrace()
        logger.debug(e.printStackTrace)
        logger.debug(e.getMessage)
    }
    }
}}
```

I am passing `schemadef` method of above class in main method of another java class which has the logic of receiving batchIds 24x7, set via custom receiver.
Functionally the application runs fine, but is taking around 15 minutes to process even 1GB of data. And if I try to simply load the data into hive table through LOAD query, it happens within a minute.

referring below configuration for spark job:

```
SPARK_MASTER    YARN
SPARK_DEPLOY-MODE   CLUSTER
SPARK_DRIVER-MEMORY 13g
SPARK_NUM-EXECUTORS 6
SPARK_EXECUTOR-MEMORY   15g
SPARK_EXECUTOR-CORES    2
```

Please let me know if you find any flaw in this or any other optimization I can do to enhance this process. Thank you

Comment: Can you try to cache it and again check for the performance . try to cache val schema  .

Comment: Why "inferschema" (which requires multiple reads of the same file) since you provide your own schema?!

Comment: Does the "foreach" process the files sequentially, or in parallel tasks (like Hive does)? If your files are tiny, does a single task process multiple files (like Hive does) or not?

Comment: You should read https://www.slideshare.net/databricks/continuous-application-with-fair-scheduler-with-robert-xue slides 6-7-8. The rest of the presentation deals with further optimizations (or rather, "good practises").

Comment: By the way https://www.slideshare.net/databricks/why-you-should-care-about-data-layout-in-the-file-system-with-cheng-lian-and-vida-ha could also give you hints about how bad things can happen when streaming small files.